# How to inline commits from a deleted branch to master in source tree

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm quite new go git and Source Tree so i started to experimenting some time ago. I have no problems with the basic stuff but i have a problem right now.

I have created a new branch and merged it with my master but since the code changes could be made without that branch I should rebase them instead of merged. I deleted this branch but somehow those commits from this branch still shows like there where on a separate branch.

[Screenshot from Source Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4xCO.png)

Can anybody explain to me how can i make those commits in one line with the commits from the master branch, have the same color etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have created a new branch and merged it with my master but since the code changes could be made without that branch I should rebase them instead of merged […]
>   Can anybody explain to me how can i make those commits in one line with the commits from the master branch, have the same color etc.

This is exactly the purpose of the **fast-forward** ("--ff" option) approach, that applies to `merge` but is mainly used when doing `git pull`. This is supposed to be set by default when possible according to the documentation, but some repositories disable it if not explicitly specified, forcing the creation of a merge point.

Apart this, you may use `cherry-pick` from master branch to manually pick up commits out of your custom branch, or force the re-creation of `master` ref on top of it.